# C++ regex_search capture retrieval fails at runtime

Tags: c++, regex, search, match

I'm following an example in Stroustrup's Tour of C++ - section 7.3.1 (page 79).  This code compiles on VS 2013 Update 3 but fails at runtime:

```
regex pat {R"(\w{2}\s+(\d{5}))"};
smatch matches;
if (regex_search(string{"CA 90210"}, matches, pat))
{
    if ((matches.size() > 1) && matches[1].matched)
    {
        cout << matches[1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Any idea what is going on?  It fails on `matches[1]` where I'm trying to output the capture group result to stdout.  The runtime assertion I see is "string iterators incompatible".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smatch` object contains iterators into the string you searched with the regular expression. Said string is a temporary in your example, and is dead by the time you are trying to inspect the matches. All those iterators are dangling.

Make it

```
string s = "CA 90210";
if (regex_search(s, matches, pat)) {...}
```

Comment: +1 Another option - `cmatch matches; if (regex_search("CA 90210", matches, pat)) ...`

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that the *string* is what is temporary; the wording is a bit ambiguous.  I puzzled for several minutes trying to figure out how `smatch` could be temporary.

Comment: @cdhowie: Duly clarified.

Comment: That works.  Thanks!  It's a bit surprising.  I thought that any object created in the condition expression would have been accessible/live within the `if` statement block.  @Praetorian - that is the first thing I tried but it doesn't compile in VS 2013 w/update 3.